# he said he had not received it vs he said he did not receive it

Tags: reported-speech

He said he had not received it vs he said he did not receive it .

Does the second sentence means that the saying and the non receiving happened quite at the same time whereas "had not received" stated that the non receiving happened before the saying .
Is it the only difference ?

Would you use the second one because as it is reported speech past simple could be understood as the original statement was in present (but received is rarely used in present)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "had" correctly in a past perfect paragraph?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/284154/how-to-use-had-correctly-in-a-past-perfect-paragraph) (which specifically asks about the choice between "had not received" and "did not receive").

Comment: not really what I need to understand is when there are two verbs like in my example is it obligatory to use past perfect to determinate which comes first . In fact I am pretty sure it is not obligatory but I would like to have a conf . As I have explained in my question if we don't do a backshift can we believe that the statement was originally done in present

Comment: I think prepending the words ***He said*** to your examples just pointlessly confuses the issue. How is the underlying issue any different if you just compare "He has not received it" with "He did not receive it"? (corresponding to the actual utterances "I have not received it" and "I did not receive it"; we can safely ignore the remote possibility of him saying "I **had** not received it").

Comment: Because using past perfect push the action of non receiving far  from the saying  and indicates which action came first .If you choose past simple for both verbs both actions are closer from each other but the meaning for both does not change

Comment: No. At the risk of repeating myself - *you're confusing the issue by irrelevantly including "He said".*  If there was no "reported backshifting" involved, there wouldn't be any ***Past** Perfect* to think about - as per my previous comment,  *we can safely ignore that remote possibility*. The only semantic difference meaningfully involved in your question is that between saying "I have not received it" and saying "I did not receive it" (which would still be "the same" question if you were comparing "He has not received it" to "He did not receive it").

Comment: (The issue being that "backshifting" gives us *He **had** not received it* from *He **has** not...*, but there is no equivalent backshifting possible if you start from *He **did** not receive it*.)

Comment: I don't really understand your answer . First I know the difference between i have not and I did not but my problem is if it is a reported speech with "he said or told "  shall I backshift or not if I choose backshifting what  effect on the meaning of the sentence and if I don't what does it change in the meaning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126555/discussion-between-user5577-and-fumblefingers).